Cannot get WiX V5 MSI installer to automatically close Windows notification application
I am upgrading an notification area application (tray app) to use a WiX V5 MSI for installation. I want my MSI to close the application if it is running before trying to install anything.  But I the WiX util:CloseApplication element seems to have no affect.
In installer project's Package.wxs file I have this:
<util:CloseApplication Id="CloseMyApp" ElevatedEndSessionMessage="yes" 
                       Target="MyTestTrayApp.exe" RebootPrompt="no" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="override Wix4CloseApplications_$(sys.BUILDARCHSHORT)" After="InstallInitialize" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>

According to WiX's documentation, when ElevatedEndSessionMessage is "yes" it should be sending WM_ENDSESSION. I created a CloseMessageFilter class, but its PreFilterMessage method never receives the message:
using System.Windows.Forms;

static class Program
{
    private class CloseMessageFilter : IMessageFilter
    {
        const int WM_CLOSE           = 0x0010;  //  Supposed to be sent if util:CloseApplication's CloseMessage attribute = "yes"
        const int WM_QUERYENDSESSION = 0x0011;  //  Supposed to be sent if util:CloseApplication's CloseMessage attribute <> "yes"
        const int WM_ENDSESSION      = 0x0016;  //  Supposed to be sent if util:CloseApplication's ElevatedEndSessionMessage = "yes"
        const int VK_CONTROL         = 0x0011;  //  But, the log file says it's attempting to send message id 17

        public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
        {
            if (m.Msg == WM_CLOSE || m.Msg == WM_QUERYENDSESSION || m.Msg == WM_ENDSESSION || m.Msg == VK_CONTROL)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(String.Format("PreFilterMessage: m.Msg = {0}", m.Msg));
                Program.Exit();
            }

            return false;
        }

        private static MyTestTrayAppContext appContext = null;

        [STAThread]
        public static void Main()
        {
            AddApplicationToStartup();
            ...some other things happen
            Application.AddMessageFilter(new CloseMessageFilter());
            appContext = new MyTestTrayContext();
            Application.Run(appContext);
        }

        public static void Exit()
        {
            appContext.myConnectorTray.Stop();
            appContext = null;

            appContext.trayIcon.Visible = false;
            Application.Exit();
        }

        public static void AddApplicationToStartup()
        {
            ....
        }
    }
}

public class MyTestTrayTrayContext : ApplicationContext
{
    public MyTestTrayContext()
    {
        ...
    }
}

When I turn on verbose logging and run the installer, the log file shows that it is trying to send a message to my application, but it's trying to send an unexpected message, sends it 6 times, then gives up:
WixCloseApplicationsDeferred:  Checking for App: MyTestTrayApp.exe Attributes: 16
WixCloseApplicationsDeferred:  Checking App: MyTestTrayApp.exe 
WixCloseApplicationsDeferred:  App: MyTestTrayApp.exe found running, 1 processes, attempting to send message.
WixCloseApplicationsDeferred:  Attempting to send process id 0x209c message id: 17
WixCloseApplicationsDeferred:  Sending message to process id 0x209c
WixCloseApplicationsDeferred:  Result 0x1
WixCloseApplicationsDeferred:  Sending message to process id 0x209c
WixCloseApplicationsDeferred:  Result 0x1
WixCloseApplicationsDeferred:  Sending message to process id 0x209c
WixCloseApplicationsDeferred:  Result 0x1
WixCloseApplicationsDeferred:  Sending message to process id 0x209c
WixCloseApplicationsDeferred:  Result 0x1
WixCloseApplicationsDeferred:  Sending message to process id 0x209c
WixCloseApplicationsDeferred:  Result 0x1
WixCloseApplicationsDeferred:  Sending message to process id 0x209c
WixCloseApplicationsDeferred:  Result 0x1

Is there something else I'm supposed to implement in my notification app to make it so the MSI installer can close it automatically?

Try to set Impersonate="yes" on the custom action. Otherwise the CA runs in the context of the local system user, which can't send messages to interactive applications. See session 0 isolation.

@zett42 Thanks but the CloseApplication element does not support an Impersonate attribute.

I was referring to the Custom element.

Same error - "The Custom element contains an unexpected attribute 'Impersonate'.

Ok, I had a misconception. Only the CustomAction attribute supports Impersonate, but that is generated automatically by util:CloseApplication. Try to replace ElevatedEndSessionMessage by EndSessionMessage. According to the docs, the former doesn't use impersonation, which implies that the latter does. https://wixtoolset.org/docs/schema/util/closeapplication/

EndSessionMessage isn't working either.  But I got it to work using a CustomAction and the ExeCommand attribute running taskkill.exe.  This does the trick for me since I have no files that need to be saved in my app that I'm killling.  The only problem is that the "Files in Use" dialog still appears telling me that MyTestTrayApp needs to be closed, even though it got killed.  But, I will start a new question for that issue.  Thanks for responding!
